# xml format eclipse attributes

Tags: xml, eclipse, format

In Eclipse Helios, it's possible to format XML like this:

```
<element
   att1="1"/>
```

But with the same settings, this won't work in Kepler or Luna, it always looks like this:

```
<element att1="1"/>
```

For two and more attributes it's the same and expected behaviour (every attribute in a separate line) in all three releases.

I'm unsure if this is a feature or some kind of a bug. Is there a way I can get the old behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it's because of the lesser value for `Line width`.
Can you check what's the line width set in both Helios & others?

Go to `Window > Preferences > XML > Editor`.

Try setting `Line width` to a higher value (like 70 or 80) depending on your preference.

Comment: Thanks for that hint, line width is set to 720, in both cases.